# Using mongoose, how do I filter and then group by?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and so far the query I use gets me all of the critiques based on a docId. I would like to group this result by distinct editors now. Except, my editors is an object.

This is what my critique query looks like:

```
 Critique.find({docId:req.params.docId}).populate('editor', 'name username').exec(function(err, critiques){
     if(err){
      console.error("Cannot find critiques with docId: " + critiques.docId);   
     }
        console.log(critiques);
        res.jsonp(critiques);
    });
```

This is my model I am querying:

```
var CritiqueSchema = new Schema({

    className : String,
    content: String,
    eleId: Number,
    type: String,
    comments: String,  
    isAccepted: Boolean,
    classes: String,
    docId:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Composition'
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    editor: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
});
```

UPDATE new query:

```
    Critique.aggregate(
   [ {$match : {docId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.docId)}},
     {$group : { _id : "$editor", critiques: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
   ]).exec(function(error, result){
          if(!error)console.log(result);
        else console.log(error); 
    });
```

Comment: Is the query working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). But `aggregation` and `population` don't go along. So you have two options `populate` and group the results by yourself by writing a loop or you can use `$group` to group them and then query each editor manually. The second is better as there will no duplication in `editor` queries whereas in `population` there will be significant duplication going on.

```
    Critique.aggregate(
   [{
      $match:
       {
         docId: ObjectId(req.params.docid)
       }
    }, 
     { $group : { _id : "$editor", critiques: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
   ],
    function(err,result){
         if(!err){
             /* result will be of the form:
                 [{_id:<an editor's objectid>,critiques:[{<critique1 document>},{<critique2 document>}...]}...]
             */
             //you will have to manually query for each distinct editor(result[i]._id) which sucks
             //because the call will be asynchronous in the loop and you can't send your response without using async library
             //another option would be to use the $in operator on an array of the distinct critiques: 
             var editors = result.map(function(x) { return x._id } );
             User.find({_id:{$in:editors}},{'username':1},function(err,editorDocs){
                    var editor_ids=editorDocs.map(function(x){return x._id})
                    var index;
                    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                      index=editor_ids.indexOf(result[i]._id);
                      result[i].editor=editorDocs[index].username;
                    }
                    //result is your final result. In the editor field of each object you will have the username of the editor
              }) 
         }
     })
```

Check [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#push-with-root) for `$$ROOT`.

Comment: This doesn't filter by a documentId. I need all the users who has commented on a specific doc and their critiques

Comment: Don't you have to specify the id as a type.objectID? I am getting an empty array back. I made my own of what you did, and I will update the post with the edit. I used some of your code, but I don't understand what $$ROOT is. Is that somewhere in the mongodb docs?

Comment: yeah we will have to cast it into ObjectId. $$ROOT is the the whole critique document. Check the edit, I think the above code should work fine.

Comment: how do I send back the editors data along with the grouped critique objects from result? I can't send two responses. How would I concatenate the two information? And what if I just wanted the username of the editor?

Comment: @CYen You can't ask for every tidbit. Anyway, check the edit. Included the linking.

Comment: sorry about that. I am new to mongodb and mongoose but know that I really appreciate your in-depth example. It's helped me by identifying the keywords that mongodb uses.